# kafka vs chronicle queue vs disruptor

Tags: java, apache-kafka, queue, messaging

Anyone can compare the underlying design and performance among kafka, chronicle queue and disruptor, in terms of logging? Seems kafka has most users but don't avoid GC.

Comment: did you come with a conclusion?

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be confused about how Kafka is used in logging pipelines - typically it's for "shipping logs" from a single process (local disk) to a log database like Elasticsearch or Splunk and the performance is going to be on the order of 100K messages/s for a single machine e.g. see https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-fastest-messaging-system/. The reason you might use Kafka is to "protect" your database from bursts e.g. https://logz.io/blog/deploying-kafka-with-elk/.

Chronicle Queue and Disrupter would be for simply writing the logs to the local disk and can achieve on the order of 10M lines/s e.g. see https://grobmeier.solutions/log4j-2-performance-close-to-insane-20072013.html#.Ue02Z2RATzc.

You might further wonder what's the point of writing 10M lines/s to disk if you can only ship 100K/s.

The reason is that you probably only write 10M lines/s when something bad is happening (or you're debugging) and only for a short period of time so if you're reading from disk into Kafka then your "reader" will get behind but can eventually catch up once the burst is over.